# JavaScript Button disabled Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Is it possible the button disabled if the bank balance is too small?
Example: Bank balance = 3 And the Button Bank Balance = 5 <- so the button is disabled

so you need a enough money that the button not disabled is!

I hope you understand what I mean and hope you can help me!

My Button :

```
<button type="sumbit" name='einzahlen' class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md">Pin einlösen</button>
```

Comment: No ! I want if a person have enough money, that the button not disabled is!

Comment: where is the value for bank balance is stored

Comment: you have to get that thing from database and if the balance is low pass that attribute in button

Comment: So how do I this ? I'm not so good! Pls help me. :)

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: We have to know a bit more information to help you.. like where is the balance stored, variable name? do you get the data via api calls.. and so on..

Comment: show your code where you get and display your balance

Comment: <?php $balance = 3; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this simple code in `jQuery`, Hope this helps you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chk').click(function(){
        var bal = parseFloat ($('.balance').text());
        if(bal <= 50){
    $('#btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="sumbit" name='einzahlen' class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md" id="btn">Pin einlösen</button>
<button id="chk">Check balance</button>
<span>Balance: </span><span class="balance">50</span>
```

Comment: Yes this is good, but how can I this without press the Check Balance?

Comment: Sry, I'm new, I don't understand what do you mean, sry :(

Comment: Delete this line " $('#chk').click(function(){ " and the last line  " }); " and check it

Comment: Okey I try this now